# What is meaning by int is not iterable?

Tags: python, class, printing, integer, typeerror

```
class Histogram:
    def __init__(self, range , max_mark):
        self.__range = range 
        self.__max_mark = max_mark
        self.__occurrence_list = [0] * self.__range
    def get_range(self):
        return self.__range
    def set_range(self, value):
        self.__range = value
    def get_max_mark(self):
        return self.__max_mark
    def set_max_mark(self, value):
        self.__max_mark = value
    def get_occurrence_list(self):
        return self.__occurrence_list
    def append_marks(self, value):
        if value > self.__max_mark:
           return 'value should be bigger than max mark'
        else:
           self.__occurrence_list[value] += 1   

 #From here is the part where I find a problem

    def draw(self):
    print(self.__occurrence_list)
    for x in len(self.__occurrence_list):
        print(x,':','*'*self.__occurence_list[x])
```

And if check an answer with this code
     a1 = Histogram(10, 9)
     a1.append_marks(0)
     a1.append_marks(10)
     a1.append_marks(8)
     a1.append_marks(2)
     a1.append_marks(8)
     a1.draw()

It says

```
for x in len(self.__occurrence_list):
   TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

but what i see is the length of self.__occurrence_list is perfectly integer.
what is the problem with my code?

Comment: You can not iterate over an integer value. You need list, dict or string etc to iterate in for loop.

Comment: Try `for x in range(len(self.__occurrence_list)):`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
for x in len(self.__occurrence_list)
```

`len` of a list will return to you the numbers of elements, but it's not something you can loop over, which is what the error message is telling you.  Apparently your intention is to loop over the indices of the list:

```
for x in range(0, len(self.__occurrence_list)):
```

This will give you a list of `n` elements which you can loop over.

Comment: The `0` base is already implied. The idiomatic way to write this is simply `for x in range(len(self.__occurrence_list)):`

Comment: The idiomatic way would be: `for index, value in enumerate(self.__occurrence_list): print(index, ':', '*' * value)`